# cannot pass parameters via angular service between 2 html file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-services

I have 2 html file and I want to  pass parameters via angular service between them.

these are the files I have:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="services.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl2">

 </div>
    <a href="enter2.html">enter here</a>
 <script>
  var app=angular.module("myApp");
  app.controller("myCtrl2", ['$scope','$location', 'myService', 
    function($scope, $location, myService) {
    myService.set("world");
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

enter2.html

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="services.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl3">
        hello {{x}} 

    </div><script type="text/javascript">
    var app=angular.module("myApp");
    app.controller("myCtrl3", ['$scope','$location', 'myService', 
        function($scope, $location, myService) {

            $scope.x=myService.get();
        }]);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

services.js

```
    var app=angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.factory('myService', function() {
     var savedData = {}
     function set(data) {
       savedData = data;
     } 
     function get() {
      return savedData;
    }

    return {
      set: set,
      get: get
    }

  });
```

why can't I get "hello world" in enter2.html, but instead get "hello" (x is not found by service)...?

Comment: You can't put script into angular templates. Also templates shouldn't have `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>`. Note errors thrown in browser console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [working example based on your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/EuNyvT1OqtnXU9JXtKpy?p=preview).

I kept your index.html and added ui-view to have a single page application. The app uses 'ui.router'.

In the myCtrl2 I saved the data in the service, and call it back from myCtrl3:

```
 .controller('myCtrl2', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    console.log('myCtrl2');
    myService.set('world');
  }])
  .controller('myCtrl3', ['myService', function(myService) {
    console.log('myCtrl3');
    var vm = this;
    vm.x = myService.get();
  }])
```

To keep things simple, I have one Javascript file:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'index.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl2',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    .state('enter2', {
      url: '/enter2',
      templateUrl: 'enter2.html',
      controller: 'myCtrl3',
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    });

  })
  .factory('myService', function() {
    var savedData = {}

    function set(data) {
      savedData = data;
    }

    function get() {
      return savedData;
    }

    return {
      set: set,
      get: get
    }

  })
  .controller('myCtrl2', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService) {
    console.log('myCtrl2');
    myService.set('world');
  }])
  .controller('myCtrl3', ['myService', function(myService) {
    console.log('myCtrl3');
    var vm = this;
    vm.x = myService.get();
  }])
```

I also uses the var vm=this and ControllerAs as often recommended to avoid $scope issues.

index.html looks like below... pleaes note the ui-sref instead of href:

```
 <div ui-view="">
    <a ui-sref="enter2">Enter here</a>
  </div>
```

enter2.html is now just the div part and your content:

```
<div>
  Hello {{ vm.x }}
</div>
```

Let us know if that helps.

Additional info:

- [AngularJS Routing Using UI-Router](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router)
- [AngularJS's Controller As and the vm Variable](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Answer (score 2):

When you go from index.html to enter2.html the whole page loads from scratch. For the data that you are expecting to stay in the browser, you might need to use advanced angular concepts such as loading just a part of the page using `ng-view`.

If that's something you have already overruled, saving the data in the service somewhere (may be the browser session) before unloading (`window.onunload` event) the page and then loading it back from there when the service loads (`window.onload` event) could also work.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a controller for your view page
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller